# Force Visual Studio 2010 to use String instead of string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010

When Visual Studio 2010 generates code (example: select option to implement an interface), it generates "string" instead of "String", even if I have defined the interface with "String" parameters.

Is there a way to get VS2010 to always generate "String". My preference is to use the .NET type names, not the C# aliases for the types.

Comment: I also have looked for this feature, neither VS2010 and resharper contain this feature...

Comment: Just curious :-) I means you also use only "Object", "Int32", "Single", etc...?

Comment: You are Jeff Atwood's favorite blog topic.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/in-programming-one-is-the-loneliest-number.html

Answer (score 2):

string is an alias of String so technically there is no difference between the two.

Comment: I'm sure the OP is aware of that. I think the question is about style ("Use .net typenames, not aliases") and how to make VS generated code conform to your style guide.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN info about `string` "The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework." So it's the same `String` and `string`.

See you